# Can't print one line from a JSON object instead of printing all in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print only one line, the first line at position 0 from a JSON object. 
I used for cycles to get into "Items" in JSON file, and another one to get into the lines, but i am not being able to select or console log just the first line. What am i doing wrong? What should i change to read only one line at position 0 or line by line?

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Users" id="filter_items"/>

<ul id="items-list">

</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var json = (function() {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'crossDomain': true,
            'method': "get",
            'url': "products.json",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ul = document.getElementById("items-list");

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // lets filters it
    input = document.getElementById('filter_items');

    var filterItems = function(event){
      keyword = input.value.toLowerCase();
      var li = "";
        for (var index in json)
        {
          for (var j in json[index])
            {
              var lines = json[index][j];
              //CONSOLE LOG HERE ONLY THE FIRST LINE


            }
        }
    }
      input.addEventListener('keyup', filterItems);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON file

```
{
    "items": [{
        "title": "Karamell Express",
        "path": "Produkter \u003e Karameller \u003e Karamell Express",
        "image": "/images/noImage.png"
    }, {
        "title": "Godisautomat",
        "path": "Produkter \u003e Bregmos \u003e Godisautomat",
        "image": "/images/noImage.png"
    }]
}
```

Comment: synchronous requests are a bad idea.

Comment: hard to know what you are doing wrong without knowing the structure of the JSON file.

Comment: I know, but my worry about this is really being able to read line by line

Comment: So what does the JSON look like?

Comment: Added that above, go check the update

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "line at position 0 from a JSON object"?

Comment: I mean: here the selected item 1 with title Karamell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json.items[0]["title"]
```

in the console I did:

```
var json = {
    "items": [{
        "title": "Karamell Express",
        "path": "Produkter \u003e Karameller \u003e Karamell Express",
        "image": "/images/noImage.png"
    }, {
        "title": "Godisautomat",
        "path": "Produkter \u003e Bregmos \u003e Godisautomat",
        "image": "/images/noImage.png"
    }]
}

json.items[0]["title"]
```

and got karamell...

Answer (score -1):

Can you show your json?
Here is a simple json example

```js
let json = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ] , [ 4, 5, 6 ] ];
json.forEach( child =>{
  child.forEach(child_child=>{
    console.log(child_child);
   })
});
```

Comment: The json was added above, how would you adapt your code snippet to mine?

Comment: This is not an answer. It would have been better suited as a comment on the original question.

Comment: Yep, i got cofused with that "answer", but thanks user9113226 anyway

Comment: @userct  use  this  :          yourJson.items.forEach(item=>{ do something here });